# Instantiate a fragment from a string from shared preferences

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-sharedpreferences

So i have an onCreate method who has a fragment transaction with a fragment called selectedFragment which I change in each menu case. I want to save that class of fragment When the app pauses to instantiate the same onResume/onRestart, so I save that fragment name in a String in SharedPreferences with the method saveInfo:

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    saveInfo();

    Toast.makeText(this, "Pause", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

protected void onResume(){
    super.onResume();

    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("selectedFragment", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    String fragmentType = sharedPreferences.getString("fragmentType", "");

    Toast.makeText(this, fragmentType, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

public void saveInfo(){
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("selectedFragment", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();

    editor.putString("fragmentType", selectedFragment.getClass().getSimpleName());
    editor.apply();
}
```

All the information is shown correctly but I can't instantiate the fragment, I tried with `selectedFragment = Fragment.instantiate(getApplicationContext(), fragmentType)` and also with `selectedFragment = Class.forName(fragmentType).newInstance();` and that returns this exception *Unhandled exception: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException*

PD: the fragmentType String I'm getting from SharedPreferences is correct.

Comment: Why complicate if it ain't needed? Use if/else to see which fragment to instantiate. Only if there's a specific reason why to avoid it like having 10-20 different possible fragments, which I doubt.

Comment: you can add the fragment to the back stack during the fragment transaction and when need check with the fragment manager using `findFragmentByTag` , passing the tag you added during the fragment transaction. if it exists, replace the existing fragment or create a new fragment and add it to the backstack. YOU CAN CREATE AN INSTANCE SIMPLY BY CALLING THE CONSTRUCTOR.

Comment: Am i not supposed to be able to instantiate a fragment from a string? I will add more fragments and that will avoid me to come every single time to change this method adding another if

Comment: [https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you really have to:

```
Fragment fragment = Class.forName("your.package.name.YourFragmentClassName").newInstance()
```